# please help me identify a font

Tags: fonts

I just came across a document with a font I like. Here is an excerpt:

[image]

As a comparison, here is a sample using mathpazo (in this second excerpt, the top line "Grading Policy" is bolded, and the rest are not):

[image]

I contacted the creator of the document but I have not gotten a reply.  I appreciate your help in identifying this font.  THANKS!

Comment: if you have the pdf your pdf reader or pdffonts program will list the fonts

Comment: whatfontis, if you limit it to free fonts, says DejaVu Serif ;-)

Comment: @carlisle's reply is correct:  In xreader (default pdf viewer of linux mint xfce)  edit -> properties -> fonts says that the original document uses dejavuseif, which agrees with rrmano's reply (stackexchange only let me quote one person per reply).  I also tried it myself and it works.  Thanks everyone!